# Jboss fuse karaf - active mq

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I am new to Jboss fuse karaf(jboss-fuse-6.3) and activeMQ.
Currently I am accessing activeMq on **localhost:61616**, my question is what is more suitable way of using activeMQ - on same server(localhost:port) or can I use activeMQ hosted on remote server, which method is more fast and safe ?

Thanks.

Comment: JBoss Fuse gives you ActiveMQ broker configured by default using OSGi methods (configadmin) or fabric profiles. If you have external broker, you have to manage it manually and simply use its URL in the applications running on Fuse. The speed is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for **dev** purpose, then the most suitable way is to use the *embedded one* that comes with Fuse out of the box because it requires less maintenance.

However if you are asking about AMQ in **production** environment then most likely it should be highly available and able to survive crashes without data losses. In this case you need to think about some failover machanism, so the safer option is to use an *external ActiveMQ broker* or even better - *a cluster* of AMQ brokers. In this case the speed of message delivery and consumption depends on the network connectivity as well.

Also if we talk about speed you should consider where AMQ should store it's messages especially the undelivered ones. By default it comes with a file based DB KahaDB which can be changed. In both cases it's fast enough.

Wish you luck with the ESB!